# How integrate Selenium code in JMeter How this is achieve

Tags: jmeter

I create a maven project using selenium web driver in eclipse to automate one web-based application. Here I  also used TestNG and the programming language Java. Now I want to integrate this selenium project into JMeter and want to do performance testing so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible to [kick off a TestNG test programmatically](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) from JMeter's [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using the code like:

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter()
TestNG testng = new TestNG()
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { YourClassWithTests.class  })
testng.addListener(tla)
testng.run()
```

I don't think you will get the results you're looking for.

The main limitations are:

1. In general [it's not advised](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/) to use Selenium for performance testing
2. You won't get [metrics and KPIs](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) like number of concurrent users, connect time, response time, etc.
3. Test will be **very** resource intensive as one instance of browser [requires 1 CPU core and a couple of gigabytes of RAM](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/99.0.1/system-requirements/) so the resource footprint will be immense.

So I would recommend [converting your Selenium tests to "pure" JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter), you can kick off JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and [configure your Selenium tests to use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/shared/#proxy), this way JMeter will be able to intercept the relevant HTTP requests and create [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers which are lightweight comparing to the real browsers and this way you will get all the metrics.